# How to verify signed XML file signature

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows-runtime, cryptography

I have a file created using [SignedXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.aspx) class in "normal" .NET framework. It's signed using RSA algorithm.
I'd like to check its signature using XDocument in a Windows RT application, what is the best way to do it? Port some crypto library or are there any other alternatives?

Comment: In WinRT you can use our SecureBlackbox, it offers wide scope of functionality including XMLDSig/XAdES and is available for WinRT.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to do it using native tools/free code/my own code. Didn't find the way to accomplish this task so far with 1st one.

Comment: This is a pretty cool question. I hope to see a reasonably thorough answer.

Comment: Certainly you can use the [Windows CryptographicEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographicengine.verifysignaturewithhashinput.aspx) You just have to make the digest yourself, which i'd assume wouldn't be too hard [XML Signature: How to calculate the digest value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245320/xml-signature-how-to-calculate-the-digest-value)

Answer (score 2):

originally it was my question and I don't know why my account was wiped from the site.Hope moderators can help with it.

@borrel, probably I didn't look too deep but anyway if you are developing something portable to get it working on Windows Phone 8, this thing doesn't exist for you. [No SignedXml in winrt](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/edfbd14e-8f12-4923-89f7-45cff9079b74/unexpected-api-differences-between-winrt-and-net)

I found an answer, so steps are

1) you have to calculate the SHA1 hash of the canonical representation of you XML data. My signature was RSA-SHA1, so needed this to get the digest value.

in "normal" framework you would use [XmlDsigc14nTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.xmldsigc14ntransform.aspx) class

Mono code provides nice samples on how you may implement this

2) use bouncy castle library to verify the rsa signature for this digest.

Comment: 2moderators : get my reputation back please or explain why you did this

Comment: you can raise an issue at meta.stackoverflow.com to ask the moderators why your account was banned.

Answer (score -1):

[SignedXml.CheckSignature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye0db953.aspx)?

it seems to be available for winrt